# Joining a series of arrays into one 'parent' array (AngularJS)

Tags: arrays, angularjs, join, multidimensional-array, concatenation

I have a series of arrays, filled with objects - in JSON format. They look something like this:

**Group 1**

```
[
    { "name" :  "John",
      "age"  :  "31"
    },
    { "name" :  "Bob",
      "age"  :  "33"
    }
]
```

**Group 2**

```
[
    { "name" :  "Jim",
      "age"  :  "46"
    },
    { "name" :  "Harry",
      "age"  :  "23"
    }
] // ... and so on ...
```

In Angular, how can I join the two arrays to form an array of arrays? I'm guessing it's `group1.concat(group2)`, or something like that? I'm not sure where to do it though, would I do this in the controller?

Currently I have a $scope property assigned to each variable, would I make a new $scope property that was a concatenated array of each of these?

And would that be something like:

```
$scope.allGroups = []

$scope.allGroups = $scope.group1.concat($scope.group2)

// since 'allGroups', 'group1', and 'group2' have all been defined can I do...

allGroups = group1.concat(group2) // ...or does $scope need to be used each time?
```

My intention is (with the necessary filters) to be able to do an ng-repeat through all groups as they will now all be linked to one $scope variable.

I'm pretty sure that's laiden with errors, but I thought it better to provide some bad code than nothing at all, just so it was more evident what I was trying to do. If there are better approaches (which I'm sure there are), I'm all ears.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How do you want the result?

Comment: Do you want to end up with one array containing John, Bob, Jim and Harry? This is not the same as an array of arrays.

Comment: Good point. Well it would be useful having it as a single array of objects, but I would like the option also of having it as an array of arrays, so each 'group' was organised as such rather than just an array of 'people', if that makes sense. In short - I'd like to know how to both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, `array1.concat(array2)` is the good method to use.

Now the question is, do you need `group1` and `group2` to be on your `$scope` ? Do you need to display them ?

If the answer is no, then you could simply do as follow:

- Recover the two arrays and store them in 2 "private" variables
- Concat them into a variable set into your `$scope`

You dont have to set variable into your `$scope` if you dont display them. It will then look like this:

```
$scope.allGroups = group1.concat(group2)
```

Otherwise, no other choice than do like you said:

```
$scope.allGroups = $scope.group1.concat($scope.group2)
```

**EDIT**

If you want an array containing the `group1` and `group2` arrays, and not only their content, you can simply use the `push()` method as follow:

```
$scope.allGroups = [];
$scope.allGroups.push(group1, group2);
```

Comment: Surely in the case of $scope.allGroups = group1.concat(group2), the fact that allGroups is attached to $scope object will make it visible... group1 and group2 won't need to be attached as they are in the new variable...?

Comment: No they don't need to, as the `concat` function creates a new object (the one that is associated to `$scope.allGroups` thus attached to your scope).

Comment: So, does array1.concat(array2) spit out one simple array filled with objects? Is there a way of making the 'allGroups' array a multi-dimensional array filled with [array1], [array2] etc... ?

Comment: It will create a new simple array. See my edit for a multi-dimensional array.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to access the concatenated array from your views you have to attach the concatenated array in the `$scope` object, so you will have to use

```
$scope.allGroups = $scope.group1.concat($scope.group2)
```

In the case that you leave `var allGroups` not attached to the `$scope` object `allGroups` will be a local variable to the controller function and will be available only through a closure

Comment: As I said above: I'm not sure why I need to attach group1 and group2 arrays to $scope, since they are being attached to allGroups, which is itself attached to $scope... ?

Comment: @Paulos3000 if for any reason both with the filtered results you need to show the individual arrays, then yes attach them to the `$scope`, otherwise dont. In general whatever is attached to the `$scope` is visible to the template and a possible overhead to the framework as it might need to be watched for changes from angular

Answer (score 1):

You can use concat() to join one array with another.
concat() function returns an array.

Here is the code:

```
 $scope.a = [1,2];
 $scope.b = [3,4];
 $scope.c = $scope.a.concat($scope.b);
```